# C++/gсс. Загрузка из txt-файла в динамический двумерный массив double?

Tags: c++, файлы, gcc, загрузка

Именно в двумерный динамический массив, не вектор векторов.

Comment: Ну а что известно? Типа, в файле в начале лежат какие-то данные о размерностях массива хотя бы?

Comment: Что именно имеется в виду под "двумерным динамическим массивом"? Существует несколько принципиально различных способов организовать двумерный динамический массив.

Answer (score 1):

Исходим из того, что любой двух, трех, n-мерный массив можно представить как линейную развертку. Так, например, следующий массив

```
int a[2][3];
```

будет представлен в памяти линейно, как одномерный массив

```
a00 a01 a02 a10 a11 a12
```

И обратно, любой одномерный массив мы можем трактовать, как многомерный. Поэтому если ты прочитаешь файл double-ов в массив известными тебе средствами:

```
// matrix.txt
10 20 30 40
20 30 40 10

// main.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v;
    std::copy((std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin)), std::istream_iterator<double>(), std::back_inserter(v));
    size_t columns = 4;
    size_t rows = v.size()/columns;
    for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
       for(size_t c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
          std::cout << v[r*columns+c] << " ";
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/KiXedQ

ты решишь поставленную задачу.